# Is there any way to connect 20-25V 1MHz digital input to arduino?

Tags: arduino

I need to connect 20-25Volts 1MHz digital input to Arduino. Are there any possible ways to do it? I think, using optocoupler will be useless because of high frequency. Any other ways to solve it?

Comment: You can use a voltage divider to reduce the voltage to a 0 to 5V range

Comment: Can the Arduino even sample that high of a frequency?

Comment: @dext0rb: The signal is said to be digital, so no ADC sampling. Perhaps interrupt based triggering.

Comment: You want a "level shifter". Dozens of ways to do it, and some basic research on this site or Google should yield an answer. If you don't understand something after performing that research, please ask a new question.

Comment: @Gustavo Litovsky, yes, you're right.

Comment: @Phil Frost, thanks for the way, didn't knew concrete term. Now see some solutions. Thanks!

Comment: It is no problem to *connect* the signal, but what do you want to *do with it*? You can detect the presence of the signal, or probably even count the pulses, but very little else.

Comment: Use a capacitor block the DC component and get 5V signal. Having it be a high frequency signal just lends it self more to using a capacitor...

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: Digital signals get sampled, too. If the microcontroller can't see both the high and low states for each cycle, aliasing will occur.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Sure. But the Op didn't specify anything about this. I assumed that he was running much faster than 1MHz to be able to do any kind of processing, so sampling wouldn't be an issue then.

Comment: The standard Arduino runs at a 16 MHz clock speed, so it still gets 8 cycles to process each edge... For implementing something like a frequency divider or counter for instance, it is easy enough to feed in a ~ 1 MHz square wave, and use the counter / dividers to deal with it, using overflow interrupts for actual processing.

Answer (score 1):

From the reference to optocouplers, presumably the source signal is not ground-referenced to the Arduino.

In such case, an optocoupler such as [Toshiba 6N137](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/143/6N137-24678.pdf) can be used. This is rated for 10 megabaud, so up to 10 MHz can be coupled using it. This optocoupler [is $0.82 at Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/6N137F/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtd3yBnp8bAgN6DNz1L1KxDhveOwOZZW7g=), but lower cost components can be found, for the much lower frequency 1 MHz signal.

A typical schematic for this would be thus:

[image: 6N137 Optocoupler application]

---

If the incoming signal is referenced to the Arduino's ground, then a simple voltage divider would work for dropping the voltage down to the required 0-5 Volts (or 0-3.3 Volts for some newer Arduino boards). Pick resistors for the divider such that their paralleled impedance is equal to or higher than the output impedance of the signal source.

This then needs to be followed up with a unity gain buffer, even a basic rail-to-rail-output single-supply op-amp as buffer or a BJT voltage follower circuit would serve.

Alternatively, the voltage-divided input could be used to switch a MOSFET, thus allowing the output to go quite close to each rail. Look for a MOSFET with logic level gate, and low gate capacitance.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the divider works assuming high enough source impedance and all that. If it's some sort of open drain output, the divider design couldget messy. Opto is probably a better bet, or a level translating buffer if there is one rated as high if the grounds can be tied together.

Comment: Agreed, adding note about buffering the input. Thanks. Don't know of level translators that do 25 Volts.

Comment: There probably exist some mil rated ones atleast, that do 24 or 28V

Comment: @ChintalagiriShashank Hmm, all I can find of that nature are some obsolete, industrial low-speed "media translation modules", typically with 4-20mA at one end, and in mere KHz ranges.

Answer (score 1):

First: Yes, you can get optocouplers with 10 MHz or faster bandwidth, so that can work. It might be easier to use a reistor divider, though. If you know the signal will always be 25V, you can use a 20 kOhm resistor between in and digital pin, and a 5 kOhm resistor between digital pin and ground, so the pin will see a 0-5V signal. If the input voltage varies so much that the lowest generated voltage is less than the "high detect" value, though, you want to use some kind of re-buffering. (Another option is an opamp, and a third option is a digital buffering chip.)

Second: For a 1 MHz signal, the Arduino only runs at 16 MHz, so you will have 8 cycles for each state of the signal (high and low.) That may not be sufficient to actually do what you need to do with the signal. However, if the signal is a protocol for which there exists peripherals (SPI, I2C, UART) then you can use that peripheral to decode it. For example, I've run 2 Mbit/s asynchronous UART servos from an Arduino, using the built-in serial port.